# Angular 9 | ngModel Provider in Directive not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms, angular9, angular2-ngmodel

I have one directive which reads the dirty state of the input control and takes some action.

Following is the code of the directive.

```
// our root app component
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][appMarkAsDirty]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class MarkAsDirtyDirective {
    @Input('appMarkAsDirty')
    parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor(private model: NgModel) { }

    @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
    onInputChange($event) {
        console.log('this.model', this.model);
        if (this.model.dirty) {
            this.parentFormGroup.markAsDirty();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, ngModel reference in the directive doesn't get updated when user types in the control. It Always remains at its initial stage i.e. value is always null and control is always touched as false and dirty as false.

This is working fine till Angular 8. And, has stopped working in Angular 9.

Link to stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxbzny

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please check invalid rather than dirty

Comment: I have edited the stackblitz. Please look at here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chz2pn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmark-as-dirty.directive.ts

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to remove the `providers` array from the directive's declaration:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][appMarkAsDirty]',
    // providers: [NgModel]
})
```

That is because if you have 2 directives, `A` and `B` and they are applied on the same element, you can inject, for instance, `A` in `B`:

#### a.directive.ts

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appA]'
})
export class ADirective {
  aDir = true

  constructor() { }

}
```

#### b.directive.ts

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appB]'
})
export class BDirective {
  bDir = true

  // Assuming `A` and `B` are applied on the same element
  // Using `@Optional()` will not throw an error in case `A` is not applied
  constructor(@Optional() private a: ADirective) {
    console.log(this.a)
  }

}
```

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/VJ5QSsTqdEfchnsjUT0t?open=app%2Fb.directive.ts)

Comment: This has answered my problem with similar directive - valueChanges was silent and removing providers: [NgModel] has fixed it, happened after upgrading to Angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

@manish I have edited the **stackblitz** URL Please cilck [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-chz2pn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image: App Component]

[[image: App component html][3]]
[image: Mark as Dirty Directive]

Comment: No, that won't work as these fields are optional. So, no required validation.

Comment: So, how would dirty directive will work on optional fields?

Comment: For dirty, it doesn't need to have any validation. It works basis if user has entered anything in the field.